# How to convert a list with values seperated by tab in each index to dictionary python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have List which reads the data from text file. The text file has 10 lines - each line separated by a TAB

list1 has below values

```
1 name1 3
2 name2 4
3 name3 5
4 name4 6
5 name5 10
6 name6 9
7 name7 100
8 name 20
9 name9 5
10 name10 2
```

I want to convert these into a Dictionary with 'name' as the Key and '1 to 10' and 'Qty(numbers you see after \t' as values.

Please suggest me on how to achieve this? I also intend to perform update/delete on these values using the key

i want my dictionary d to look like below
d={name1:[value1,value2],name2:[value1,value2].....}

Comment: `[00 = {str} '1 \tname1\t3'` doesn't look like valid python syntax to me. Please fix it to be a [mcve].

Comment: my apologies. I pulled it from debug mode... if i print my list - it looks like
1 name1 3
2 name2 4
3 name3 5
4 name4 6
5 name5 10
6 name6 9
7 name7 100
8 name 20
9 name9 5
10 name10 2

Comment: Please include an example of the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all your strings are of the form `'1 \tname1\t3'`, the easiest way is

```
d = {}
for s in list:
    sp = s.split('\t')
    d[sp[1]] = sp[2] # <==> name1 = 3
```

Comment: I just corrected the way my list is looking. can i just replace \t with a space?

Comment: it is still creating the dictionary with one key and one value. I want to create one key with two values..... Please correct me on what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out
instead of reading from the list- i directly read from the file into the dictionary

```
my_dict = {}
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split("_")
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        my_dict[key] = values
for x in my_dict:
    print(x,my_dict[x])
```